# Is there a Java / Scala implementation for entering Hbse Puts that actually shows the result of the transaction

Tags: java, scala, client, hbase

I am seeing that one of my Hbase entries is not working. I would like to have a Hbase method for a Java / Scala Hbase client that shows the result of entering the Puts into the Hbase Table?
There does not seem to be any entries concerning transactions in Hbase.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see my another answer here , you can use batch put to get an exception back for that particular put. It means, if array contains a Throwable instance for that index then that put failed.

Please read this answer for details. [Are HBase Batch Operations Atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144537/are-hbase-batch-operations-atomic/35157067#35157067)

Comment: Implementing batch in my code, and then checking the contents of the Object[] results just shows me the following: "keyvalues=NONE" . I am guessing as this is not NULL then this is fine. Is this as granular as we can check the behaviour of Hbase actions? I would have hoped there could be some transaction debug logging for this case.

Comment: generally table manipulating operations throw IOException on java api, so you can check one by one. What do you mean by transaction? hbase has only row scope transaction support. for example if one Put operation adds multiple columns, all columns added or none of them added.